# How to convert scrape table data to a dictionary with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have table as follows:

```
<table class="vinInfoTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="caption">VIN</td>
      <td>W1K2052131G080816</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="caption">TYPE</td>
      <td>C 300 de Estate</td>
    </tr>
    ....
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I scrape it with Python Selenium. My code is as follows:

```
vin_info_table = dialog_box[0].find_element_by_css_selector('table.vinInfoTable')
for row in vin_info_table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    for idx, cell in enumerate(row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')):
         print("IDX: {}".format(idx))
         print(cell.text)
```

What I want is to get a result as a **dictionary** where every **td** with class **caption** will be the *key* and the other td in that tr will be a *value*. Thus, the result should be as follows:

```
result = {
  "VIN": "W1K2052131G080816",
  "TYPE": "C 300 de Estate",
  ....
}
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way, but it works!

```py
# get all `caption` class td in `vinInfoTable` class table
target_td = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.vinInfoTable td.caption")

# get tr by `caption` class td
trs = [i.find_element_by_xpath('..') for i in target_td]

contents = dict()

for tr in trs:
    # get this tr's td
    tds = tr.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")
    contents[tds[0].text] = tds[1].text
```

contents value will be

```
{'VIN': 'W1K2052131G080816', 'TYPE': 'C 300 de Estate'}
```